# Azure api management Version routing duplicaiton to function

Tags: azure-functions, azure-api-management

Having a weird issue with API development, just wondering if anyone knows the solution/what I have done wrong?

I have an API `http://company/api/products` which is an azure function that works correctly, and is set up as a single api in api management.
Using azure api management I created a new version which has the version identifier of `v2` so the link becomes `http://company/api/v2/products`

But I find this link just points to the original API still, and not the new version(Route c# code below). I find that if I change the frontend URL of my products api in the new version to `/v2/products` rather than `/products`, it does work, but that means that my URL is now
`http://company/api/v2/v2/products`, which isn't what I wanted.

I COULD create a new version with no identifier (maybe?) and set the path of each url manually, but expected a new version to create the new route as well, and would prefer that for maintenance reasons

in my c# code/function I have new method with a `httpTrigger` that looks like this; locally it works 100% correctly (or on /v2/v2/products it works)

```
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "v2/products")] HttpRequest request,
```

It's like the version identifier isn't used in the route at all, is there something I'm missing to pick it up?

Answer (score 1):

In the API Management Publisher portal, you can update the Backend API URL for the new version as `http://{backend api base url}/v2`

This way any request that is going to the backend api will be routed correctly.

Comment: But then the api identifier makes it /v2/v2/

Comment: What do you mean by API identifier? By doing above, we are setting the version identifier in the path for the back end calls. Since we are modifying the route settings, the user who is using the API management front end API url will not see two v2s